# How can I pass an int variable value from one activity to overwrite a textview in another activity

Tags: java, android

Im new to android programming. I have a set of edittexts and I wrote a code to get the value of the user's input and perform a mathematical calculation. the final value from the calculation is stored in an int variable. how do I get the value of this int variable to overwrite the content of a textview in another activity...here's some bit of code I wrote

```
Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1next);    
        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                double  readValue15= Double.valueOf(edit15watt.getText().toString());
                    readValue15= readValue15 * 15;
                    final Intent a = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Summary.class);
                    a.putExtra("value", readValue15);
                    startActivity(a);
    -------------------------------------------------
```

on the other activity, I have this code written down.

public class Summary extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);


    int valueone = getIntent().getIntExtra("value",);
    TextView watt15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    watt15.setText("The total power consumed by 15watt bulbs is" +valueone);
                 .................
```

but whenever I launch the app, it gives me a result like
"the total  power consumed by 15watt bulbs is 0". I want it to display the value of the int variable created in the previous activity. can someone help?

Comment: try with `readValue15= 1* 15;`, and tell me what happens?

Comment: it doesnt work...i removed the readvalue and now I get "null" (The total power consumed by 15watt bulbs is null)

Comment: `a.putExtra("value", 15);` check this code and tell me what happens?

Comment: it displays 15...but that is not what I want. I want it to display a value that result from the multiplication of whatever value the user enters in and 15. its the result I want to be displayed

Comment: If so, You have to check your `readValue15` only, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this,

You are passing string from one activity and you need to use the following code in another activity:

```
double valueone = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("value", "0");

    TextView watt15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    watt15.setText("The total power consumed by 15watt bulbs is" +valueone);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me know what happens after you try this.

Comment: nope...it only displayed the value of 0. i.e ( the total poser consumed by 15 watt bulbs is 0)

Comment: Yes it is displaying zero because as per the statement if proper value is not received it will display zero. This means the value which your are sending is not received here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float readValue15 = Float.valueOf(edit15watt.getText().toString()) * 15f;
```

Note the **f** after **15**.  Your problem might be due to a loss in precision.

Comment: I did as you said. it overwrote the textviews content to a float value but that value is 0.0. let me explain my question more clearly. I have an edittext field and when I input a value into it, I want whatever value I input to be stored in a variable. this variable is then used for a particular mathematical calculation and then after this calculation is done, the resulting value is used to overwrite the content of a textview in a different activity.

Comment: for example, EditText edit15watt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit15watt);(to declare the edittext), then, Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1next); (to declare a button). then I created an onclick listener so that when the button is clicked, it performs this @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        
    double  readValue15= Double.valueOf(edit15watt.getText().toString());
     readValue15= readValue15 * 15;

Comment: /*after this, I create two intents*/                                                           final Intent a = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Summary.class);
     a.putExtra("value", readValue15);
     
     Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cooling.class);
     startActivity(b);

Comment: At the other activity, I am doing this                                                double valueone = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("readValue15", 0); 
 
 
 TextView watt15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 watt15.setText("The total power consumed by 15 watt bulbs is"+ String.valueOf(valueone));

Comment: My advice would be to use `Log.d()` along the way and see precisely where the value changes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're putting a float value in bundle and getting an int value. Get float instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in second activity to this code.You will definitely get the result what you want.

```
Intent i=getIntent();
int valueone = (int)i.getDoubleExtra("value",0);
TextView watt15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
watt15.setText("The total power consumed by 15watt bulbs is" +valueone);
```

Comment: dint work. I belive there should be a way...the value I want to be displayed is the readvalue15. the valueone just happens to be an object variable created for receiving the getextra